# Symfony: Service in other Service not loaded (Too few arguments)

Tags: php, dependency-injection, service, autowired, symfony5

#### Background

I have a `OptionHelper`-Class that is looking in the database-table, where I store some flexible parameters. This class is working fine in Controllers.

Now I want to use this class in a function of another Service, but it explodes with the below mentioned error message.

#### OptionHelper.php

```
namespace App\Service;


use App\Entity\Options;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class OptionHelper {
    private $emi;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $emi) {
        $this->emi = $emi;
    }

    public function get(string $optionName) {
        $repository = $this->emi->getRepository(Options::class);
        $options    = $repository->findOneBy([ 'optionname' => $optionName ]);
        $value      = $options->getOptionvalue();

        return $value;
    }
}
```

#### CartItem.php

```
namespace App\Service

class CartItem {
    [...]
    public function __construct($name, $number, $id) {
        $this->name   = $name;
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->id     = $id;
    }
    [...]
    private function getPrice(OptionHelper $optionHelper) { //<-- ERROR in this line
        $price = $optionHelper->get('price');    
        return $price;
    }
}
```

#### Controller

```
   [...]
   public function addItem($name, $number, $id) {
      $cartItem = new CartItem($name, $number, $id);
   }
```

#### Error-Msg

```
Too few arguments to function App\Service\CartItem::getPrice(), 0 passed in /src/Service/CartItem.php on line 89 and exactly 1 expected
```

### Question

Why isn't it working in another Service? I tried also to put it into the constructor of `CartItem`-Class, but doesn't work too.

Do I have to add something in `services.yaml`? But I have no idea, how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while I found the problem.
It seems that you should never do this, because it disables the autowiring functionality.

- use `new ClassName($x, $y)` to create a new instance
- only use autowirable Services in the constructor of a class

#### wrong

```
    public function __construct($name, $number, $id) {
        $this->name   = $name;
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->id     = $id;
    }
```

```
   public function addItem($name, $number, $id) {
      $cartItem = new CartItem($name, $number, $id);
   }
```

#### correct

```
    public function __construct(OnlyServices $onlyServices) {
       [...]
    }

    public function create($name, $number, $id) {
        $this->name   = $name;
        $this->number = $number;
        $this->id     = $id;
    }
```

```
   public function addItem($name, $number, $id, CartItem $cartItem) {
      $cartItem->create($name, $number, $id);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the services to be injected automatically, you must set autowiring and autoconfigure option to true in your service.yaml as explained in symfony docs:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html

Like this:

config/services.yaml

```
services: 
       _defaults: 
              autowire: true 
              autoconfigure: true
```

Comment: Hey, many thanks for taking time for my problem. Unfortunatelly this does not help. These two options had already been set to true by the standard `config/services.yaml` from the installation and had never been touched. Any other idea?

Comment: Have you tried injecting service into constructor of class:CartItem instead of getItem function.

Comment: php bin/console debug:autowiring use this command to check if your service is listed under autowiring or not.

Comment: yes, it is. As mentioned, I use the `OptionHelper`-Class in an Controller too and there it works fine.